# appending a predicate / filter to all queries of a table

Tags: sqlalchemy

Does SQLAlchemy allow us to define the Table (or Query) such that a specific predicate is automatically appended to all queries on that table? The queries can even come via relationships/associations. I am trying to avoid adding a filter() to every query expression in every module.

Example: 
table T1 has column col1 and I want every sqla query on that table to automatically add an extra predicate col1='Y' before submitting sql to db.

I want the resulting queries involving t1 object to be like these:
select .. from t1 where ... and **t1.col1='Y'**
select .. from t2 join t1 on t2.x=t1.x where ... and **t1.col1='Y'**

This was easily doable in hibernate by adding **WHERE="col1='Y'"** attribute in xml mapping of table or relationship. (This how it was done in hibernate at least 5 years ago).

I am using declarative base with autoload=True in SQLA version 0.9

Comment: Can you be more specific here? What type of filter would you need to add to every single query? Please provide some code showing what you currently have and what you'd rather it look like.

Comment: @jonafato I have added a sql based example. Let me know if I should add sqla code also. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two recipes for how to achieve this behavior:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/GlobalFilter