# How can I do this in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy model, say `Entity` and this has a column, `is_published`. If I query this, say by id, I only want to return this if `is_published` is set to `True`. I think I can achieve using a filter. But in case there is a relationship and I am able to and require to access it like `another_model_obj.entity` and I only want this to give the corresponding entity object if the `is_published` for that instance is set to `True`. How should I do this? One solution would be wrap this around using an if block each time I use this. But I use this too many times and if I use it again, I will have to remember this detail. Is there any way I can automate this in SQLAlchemy, or is there any other better solution to this problem as a whole? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads as if you would need a join:

```
session().query(AnotherModel).join(Entity).filter(Entity.is_published)
```

Comment: IIRC you can even leave out the explicit `.join` and write `...query(Entity, AnotherModel).filter(...)`.

Comment: you could probably do this, but then AnotherModel instances will be part of the result set

Comment: Of course for stuff in the model and service files I use something like this. For views, I abort with a 404. But in some inevitable template usage where I can't put a full blown query, what can I do?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you need the query, do it. There's no reason not to do a join when the information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked many times here and still doesn't have a good answer. [Here are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20776170/168352) possible solutions suggested by the author of SQLAlchemy. A more elaborate query class to exclude unpublished objects [is provided in iktomi library](https://github.com/SmartTeleMax/iktomi/blob/master/iktomi/unstable/db/sqla/public_query.py). It works with SQLAlchemy 0.8.* branch only for now but should be ported to 0.9.* soon. See [test cases](https://github.com/SmartTeleMax/iktomi/blob/master/tests/unstable/db/sqla/public_query.py) for limitations (tests that fail are marked with `@unittest.skip()`) and usage examples.